# Normally, which one would you like to choose? Past simple or past perfect?

Tags: tenses

Now my problem was, how was I going to get back to my farm stay house? I ________ a map with me.

1. A. didn’t bring
2. B. hadn’t brought
3. C. hadn’t been bringing

Comment: The "Now my problem was" intro suggests a [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) tense continuation. But the embedded sentence begins "how *was* I ...*, so the writer decided to pass on the historical present tense. So (B) seems like the best continuation. Had the writer gone with "how am I to get back ...", (A) would be a valid option. The comma after *was* doesn't belong there. There are several options for setting off embedded statements, but don't use a comma after the verb.

Answer (score 0):

You cite 3 options:

A - simple past, negative form ('did not bring')
The positive form would be 'brought'.
This implies that the action either took place 1 step back in the past, or that it happened regularly.
The action you refer to (bringing a map with you) cannot have taken place at the same time as you realised you had not brought it.
The regular act of bringing a map with you doesn't seem right - you mention 'a map', not 'the map'.

B - past perfect, negative form ('had not brought')
The positive form would be 'had brought'.
This is the correct form to use as it refers to an action that started 2 steps back in the past and is completed 1 step back in the past.

C - past continuous, negative form ('had not been bringing')
The positive form would be 'had been bringing'
This implies a continuous action - 'had been bringing the map while ...' which doesn't apply here.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much @ Leon. 
All I confused was why not A. Your answer explained that perfectly. Normally, I will answer somebody's question about "Why cannot you get back....". --I didn't bring a map with me. If I narrative the whole sentence with "didn't bring", that means I omitted the "why".
However, if there is no Why sentence or clause, I should say "I hadn't brought" cause it implies an action 1 step back in the past what I mentioned in my last words. Am I right?